# SharePoint On Premise with AzureAD SAML 1.1 WS-Federation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, azure-ad, sso

I feel as though I am so close, but only missing a little configuration. I am posting in hope that someone could help me out.   I have configured SharePoint 2013 on Premise for outside contractors to use Azure AD Single Sign-On with SAML 1.1 and WS-Federation according to the following article - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/using-azure-ad-for-sharepoint-server-authentication

[image: SharePoint Login Choices]

Then after the login, I get the following from fiddler

[image: Fiddler]

And I get the following error from SharePoint -

[image]

sharePoint.stackexchange.com teammates can you help me with finding the missing piece? Because from what I am seeing the AzureAD is getting inside - And to also note, the end-user, which is added to the Azure AD enterprise application, Web Application Policy, and the actual Site Collection (Full Rights on everything).

I will keep troubleshooting until I find a solution.  This is the final piece of the puzzle that is missing.

Lastly - If anybody has done this before I would rather bypass the sign-in page for Windows Auth users and only require AzureAD users to login.  If anybody has that expertise, I would be grateful.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you look the correlation id(under something went wrong page) in the ULS logs on your WFE and share with us?

Comment: Unexpected System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException: ID4014: A SecurityTokenHandler is not registered to read security token ('Assertion', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion').

Comment: Check this for configuring SharePoint on prem with Azure AD: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sharepoint-on-premises-tutorial